# how to setup PasswordAuthenticated proxy using HttpURLConnection?

Tags: java, proxy, network-programming, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to setup a proxy connection and I would like to avoid using System properties as they would apply globally. When I try the code below:

```
package com.cheyrico2.Test;

import static java.net.Proxy.Type;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.Proxy;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

import sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        URL urlObject = null;
        try {
            urlObject = new URL(null, "https://www.google.com", new Handler());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        final String userName = "proxyUserName";
        final String password = "proxyPassword";
        Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(userName, password.toCharArray());
            }
        });
        Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("httpProxyServer", 6060));
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObject.openConnection(proxy);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        } catch (ProtocolException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            conn.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        InputStream bodyStream = null;
        try {
            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            if (responseCode >= 400 || responseCode == -1) {
                bodyStream = conn.getErrorStream();
            } else {
                bodyStream = conn.getInputStream();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String result = getResponse(bodyStream);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    private static String getResponse(InputStream bodyStream) {
        String result = null;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(bodyStream);
        try {
            s.useDelimiter("\\A");
            result = s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
        } finally {
            s.close();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

I get the following error. It seems that the connection cannot find the credential to use.

```
java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.0 407 Proxy Authentication Required"
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.doTunneling(HttpURLConnection.java:2124)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:183)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
    at com.cheyrico2.Test.App.main(App.java:54)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:72)
    at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:563)
    at com.cheyrico2.Test.App.main(App.java:69)
```

I've verified my proxy server connection using a web browser and it works but this does not seem to work. What am i missing? Any suggestion would be highly appreaciated.

Comment: It seems that you don't need to explicitly set `Proxy-Authorization` if you already pass `Proxy` and configure default `Authenticator`. And... if you add a breakpoint (or debug printout) inside your `Authenticator`, does it trigger?

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy it does not trigger getPasswordAuthentication

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy what can I do to Trigger getPasswordAuthentication?